# Choosing between NoSQL and Relational databases while having both flexibility and consistency requirements

Tags: database-design, nosql, consistency

I've never worked with databases professionally and only toyed with database coding using a small sqlite db for my own music collection. Now I'm asked to build an internal database system at work for multiple users. After basic reading of NoSQL vs. relational databases, I'd like to have some ideas on how to choose the right technology.

### Context

- Before this database, the users work with spreadsheets entirely.
- Those sheets differ in structure (schema) from project to project.
- Sometimes the same project has several different sheets that need to be isolated but still exist in the same database.
- We want to import all those sheets into a database and with new fields added and old fields names/values updated on the fly without breaking the original spreadsheets
- When source control ops happen, we want to be able to connect to the database and update certain fields regarding the source control management status
- The database will be used by various users from different locations, all through the in-house network for now. There won't be a lot of users like on Facebook or Twitter.
- All the data must be localized into multiple languages and ideally co-exist in the same database.

### Questions

- Since we'll have different sheet structures, is NoSQL a better option than a relational database?
- The users will go on using spreadsheets and may change their sheet structure on the fly. Will this be a lot of trouble for NoSQL or relational databases such as SQLite?
- NoSQL does not support the ACID of relational databases, does it mean that data may get corrupted when multiple users work on the same record? We normally would like consistency.
- If we maintain an optimized database but still want to be able to export selected portions or entire as CSV or JSON files? Will NoSQL or relational work better?
- How to handle access control from scratch if we do it online? Will this affect the choice of database tech?
- For this type of system, should we hire a database expert dev and/or maintainer? Can we build on some free/open-source infrastructure that requires the least amount of backend/frontend, security tech R&D?

Thanks for your input in advance!

Comment: This is a wide, wide set of questions and not really suitable for the site. You're looking for a consultant, effectively from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions directly:

1. "*Since we'll have different sheet structures, is NoSQL a better option than a relational database?*"

   A. Probably not, unless each of those *sheet structures* are very tightly related as one application that they'd all be stored in the same few tables. Otherwise it sounds like you just have a series of structured datasets (multiple applications) that can be represented each with their own different set of tables. This is quite normal and can easily be implemented in either a **Relational Database Management System (RDBMS)** or a **NoSQL** database, so no differentiation here.
2. "*The users will go on using spreadsheets and may change their sheet structure on the fly. Will this be a lot of trouble for NoSQL or relational databases such as SQLite?*"

   A. Are the spreadsheets consumers of the data that was saved down to the database, i.e. besides writing to the database do the spreadsheets also need to read back from the database? If so, then changing structures is something you'll need to handle regardless of which type of database you use, the problem just occurs at different layers of the application. With a **RDBMS** you need a process to handle managing schema changes in the database that have occurred at the client, otherwise your database won't be storing any new data that is entered. With a **NoSQL** database, your problem exists in the other direction, when pulling data back into the client's new schema but the instance of data from **NoSQL** is still out of date and doesn't match the client. With Excel, it may actually be more forgiving though and just leave those columns blank. But keep in mind **Consistency** is also different in **NoSQL** should you choose to distribute the data across multiple nodes. It is *eventually consistent*, which means one user of a spreadsheet may receive a different version of the schema vs another user of that same spreadsheet, if the data from the newer structure hasn't been replicated to the other node yet. More of this on the answer to your next question.
3. "*NoSQL does not support the ACID of relational databases, does it mean that data may get corrupted when multiple users work on the same record? We normally would like consistency.*"

   A. **NoSQL** follows the [**BASE principles**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382260/5059085) (and is bound by the [**CAP theorem**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)), which means unlike a **RDBMS** that follows the **ACID** principals, it is **eventually consistent**. This means a change to the database, including the change of the data itself, is not guaranteed to instantly be replicated across all nodes of which that database is distributed across. But it will be **eventually** replicated and **consistent** across all nodes. In regards to your question, that does not mean data is any more likely to be corrupted (from the system's perspective) if you use a **NoSQL** database vs a **RDBMS** and multiple users are changing the same record. Rather, it just means that the same record could be in multiple different states at the same time between different nodes, until the *last in* (generally) change becomes synchronized across all nodes of that database so that it becomes **eventually consistent**. A **RDBMS** generally employs an algorithm with a locking mechanism to ensure that **consistency** is immediate and that the same record is never in more than one state at a time.
4. "*If we maintain an optimized database but still want to be able to export selected portions or entire as CSV or JSON files? Will NoSQL or relational work better?*"

   A. At a high level, I don't believe you'll find any differences here between either. It's an equally achievable goal for both types of database systems, and the differences will be very low level detail specific as you're getting into it. Some **RDBMS** natively support storing and/or exporting the data as **JSON** and **CSV** formats, and typically **NoSQL** databases already store (or retrieve) data as **JSON** and there should be ways to convert the results to **CSV** with modern implementations of those databases.
5. "*How to handle access control from scratch if we do it online? Will this affect the choice of database tech?*"

   A. By "*doing it online*" do you mean a cloud-based solution? If so, this shouldn't change anything from a security standpoint. Either way, all modern database systems have a way to setup accounts either directly in the database system itself or mapped to another security system. For example, the Microsoft SQL Server database system offers the ability to either create dedicated **Logins** to the database or leverage **Active Directory** such that you can define access control within the database on top of **Windows Users** and **Groups**, and this still functions the same even when using Azure (Microsoft's cloud solution) to host your database. Similar ideas apply to other modern database systems too.
6. "*For this type of system, should we hire a database expert dev and/or maintainer? Can we build on some free/open-source infrastructure that requires the least amount of backend/frontend, security tech R&D?*"

   A. You sound like you have a lot of questions and thinking to do around the problems you're planning to solve, so if it's possible, hiring someone with strong database experience (especially one who has worked with both **RDBMS** and **NoSQL**) would be only of a benefit to you. Currently with the information you provided and based on the questions you've asked, I don't objectively see any distinguishing factor to choose one type of database system over another. My only subjective opinion would be to go with a **RDBMS** since it sounds like your data is structured at least (even if it does change - that's fine in a **RDBMS**) and if the **eventual consistency** of **NoSQL** can be an issue for your use-cases. If you're looking for an open source and free **RDBMS** then I'd recommend looking into PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough answer! This clears up the issues a lot. Yes, I am convinced that we need an expert on board.